# Pipenv global environment

Tags: python, pipenv

Pipenv is a good tool for managing python environments. But some things need to be global. For instance most command line tools should be always available and jupyter for use with non python kernels.

Can pipenv be used to manage such a global python environment as well? If so, how? Is this a sane thing to do?

Answer (score 14):

**Installing from Pipenv without a virtual environment**

I had a similar problem to you - I needed to install dependencies globally on our production server.

I came across [this discussion](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/813) which alerted me to the [`--system`](https://pipenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#cmdoption-pipenv-install-system) option.  `pipenv install --system` installs dependencies globally.

**Installing *only some* dependencies globally**

There are a couple of other aspects of your question which I thought I should address too:

First of all, you talk about "some" things being global.  If you have some dependencies which need to be global and some which need to be in a virtual environment, you could split them into separate Pipfiles and use the [`PIPENV_PIPFILE`](https://pipenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/#pipenv.environments.PIPENV_PIPFILE) environment variable.  For example:

```bash
# Install your global deps from a separate file
$ PIPENV_PIPFILE="/path/to/global/deps/Pipfile" pipenv install --system

# Use your local Pipfile for the project-specific deps (in a virtual environment as normal)
$ pipenv install
```

**An alternative: pipsi**

Secondly, you ask "is this a sane thing to do?"  I think is is sane to use Pipenv for global dependencies in general, but for your use case of command-line tools, I would use [pipsi](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/pipsi).  Pipsi installs libraries globally but isolated from each other (see the link for more details).  However, I don't think it offers a way of using a requirements file ([ref](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/pipsi/issues/13)).

For some general reading about Python setup and dependencies, I really recommend Jacob Kaplan-Moss's article [My Python Development Environment, 2018 Edition](https://jacobian.org/2018/feb/21/python-environment-2018/).

Comment: For production environments, the [`--deploy`](https://pipenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#cmdoption-pipenv-install-deploy) option is also useful: "Abort if the Pipfile.lock is out-of-date, or Python version is wrong.".

Comment: Update: pipsi is no longer maintained; [pipx](https://pypi.org/project/pipx/) is [recommended](https://jacobian.org/2019/nov/11/python-environment-2020/) instead.

Comment: is it possible to use global packages in a pipenv project, along with the local packages?

Comment: @vikrant, you'd have to split the local and global into separate Pipfiles - see "Installing only some dependencies globally" above.

Comment: sure, but can a project import the packages from both locations, global and local

Comment: oh sorry, I see what you mean.  I think that would work, but I've not tried it, sorry.

Comment: No prob, I think I will install all packages in a virtual environment, and then create separate folders within it to separate the projects. This way I don't have to install same package again and again

Comment: Hey @vikrant, could you guide me how you could try your solution for this?
I need to do exactly same thing... My wondering is how other python devs didn't face your use case exactly so far.. It's common to import globally installed packages across multiple virtual environments.