# Is there a way to make PipEnv install in whatever Python environment is currently active?

Tags: python, pip, pipenv

If you have no virtualenv active, PipEnv will create a virtualenv and then activate it before installing packages. If you have a virtualenv active, PipEnv will use that and not create a new virtualenv. Those are the normal use-cases for PipEnv.

But what if I'd like to totally disregard virtualenv? Quite often I work out of Docker Containers. I'd like to install a PipEnv based project, but not in a virtualenv. When I `pipenv sync` from within a Docker container I want everything installed into the container's global Python interpreter.

It simply wouldn't make sense to put a virtualenv inside a container - that's one more layer of virtualization than I actually need.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pipenv global environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51554241/pipenv-global-environment)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpipenv%5D+without+virtual+environment